# Ngrx createEffect type error after angular 15->16 update

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I'm currently trying to update an application from angular 15 -> 16.
However with the new type enforcements in ngrx I'm getting compiler errors that I'm not managing to figure out the solution for.

Historically we had

```
//Actions:
export const RESET_ORDER_IDENTIFIER = '[ServiceProvisioning] Reset order identifier';
export const RESET_ORDER_IDENTIFIER_SUCCESS = '[ServiceProvisioning] Reset order identifier success';

export const resetOrderIdentifier = createAction(RESET_ORDER_IDENTIFIER);
export const resetOrderIdentifierSuccess = createAction(RESET_ORDER_IDENTIFIER_SUCCESS, props<{ orderIdentifier: string}>());

//Effect:
  resetOrderIdentifier$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ServiceProvisioningActions.resetOrderIdentifier),
      map(() => {
        //generateGUID() returns a random string (not an observable)
        return ServiceProvisioningActions.resetOrderIdentifierSuccess({orderIdentifier: this._utilsService.generateGUID()});
      })
    );
  });
```

this gives the error

```
Argument type () => 
Observable<{orderIdentifier: string} & TypedAction<"[ServiceProvisioning] Reset order identifier success">> 
is not assignable to parameter type () => 
(Observable<{orderIdentifier: string} & TypedAction<"[ServiceProvisioning] Reset order identifier success">> & 
ConditionallyDisallowActionCreator<DispatchType<EffectConfig & 
{functional?: false}>, Observable<{orderIdentifier: string} & 
TypedAction<"[ServiceProvisioning] Reset order identifier success">>>)
```

Another createEffect giving me trouble is

```
//Actions:
export const SET_SELECTED_SERVICE_TYPE_ACTION = '[ServiceProvisioning] Set selected service type';
export const SET_SELECTED_SERVICE_TYPE_ACTION_SUCCESS = '[ServiceProvisioning] Set selected service type success';
export const setSelectedServiceType = createAction(SET_SELECTED_SERVICE_TYPE_ACTION, props<{ selectedServiceType: ServiceProvisioningState['selectedServiceType'] }>());
export const setSelectedServiceTypeSuccess = createAction(SET_SELECTED_SERVICE_TYPE_ACTION_SUCCESS, props<{ selectedServiceType }>());


//Effect:
  setSelectedServiceType$ = createEffect( () => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ServiceProvisioningActions.setSelectedServiceType),
      switchMap( ({ selectedServiceType }) => {
        let pageTitle = selectedServiceType.includes('foo') ? 'foo bar' : 'bar';
        this._store.dispatch(ServiceProvisioningActions.setPageTitle({pageTitle}));
        return of (ServiceProvisioningActions.setSelectedServiceTypeSuccess({selectedServiceType}));
      })
    );
  });
```

Gives a similar error

```
Argument type () => 
Observable<{selectedServiceType} & TypedAction<"[ServiceProvisioning] Set selected service type success">> 
is not assignable to parameter type () => 
(Observable<{selectedServiceType} & TypedAction<"[ServiceProvisioning] Set selected service type success">> & 
ConditionallyDisallowActionCreator<DispatchType<EffectConfig & {functional?: false}>, Observable<{selectedServiceType} &
 TypedAction<"[ServiceProvisioning] Set selected service type success">>>)
```

Any help with migration docs that mention this that I'm failing to find, or how these functions are meant to be written would be appreciate, Cheers.
Note: I have left out the reducer/state as I don't think the problem is related to how those are set up and wanted post to be to the point, but can add if required

Comment: Thanks for being my rubber duck.

I have a change to the first one 
```  resetOrderIdentifier$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ServiceProvisioningActions.resetOrderIdentifier),
      switchMap(() => {
        const subs = [];
        subs.push(ServiceProvisioningActions.resetOrderIdentifierSuccess({orderIdentifier: this._utilsService.generateGUID()}));
        return subs;
      })
    );
  });
```
and will continue with that method and see if we compile...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this off.

Combination of above fix's (some cases had to be changed from returning arrays of subs to single sub to work ) as well as replacing instances of 'return of(foo)' with sub.next() or store dispatch.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the first example with returning an array of subs resolved my original issue

Fix:

```
  resetOrderIdentifier$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ServiceProvisioningActions.resetOrderIdentifier),
      switchMap(() => {
        const subs = [];
        subs.push(ServiceProvisioningActions.resetOrderIdentifierSuccess({orderIdentifier: this._utilsService.generateGUID()}));
        return subs;
      })
    );
  });
```

Another common issue we had was when using concactFromLatest

Previously we had

```
savePlanSelectionFormValues$ = createEffect(() => {
  return this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(ServiceProvisioningActions.savePlanSelectionFormValues),
    concatLatestFrom((a: ServiceProvisioningState) => this._serviceProvisioningState.select(selectServiceProvisioningState)),
    switchMap(([ { planSelectionFormValues }, serviceProvisioningState ]) => {.....
```

Now its

```
  savePlanSelectionFormValues$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ServiceProvisioningActions.savePlanSelectionFormValues),
        exhaustMap(({planSelectionFormValues}) => {
          this._serviceProvisioningState.select(selectServiceProvisioningState).pipe(
            map((serviceProvisioningState) => {
```

The most recent error I had was around this

```
 return of(storeAcation.actionError({error}));
```

Fixed with

```
   
return of({
  type: storeAcation.actionError,
  payload: { error }
});
```

I will continue to update this comment until I have finished the refactor, then mark as resolved

Comment: This just tricks the type system as `subs` will be of type `any[]`, doesn't it...?

Comment: You are correct, and while it made it compile, when testing it further I ran into cases that didnt work. I forgot to update this in the end, but minor changes such as rather than returning an array of subs and pushing a new sub for each action, I had to return a single sub and fire .next() n number of times. I did also need to change 'return of(action)' with either a store.dispatch or sub.next(action).
Cheers for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered the same issue with an **outdated WebStorm** version. The NgRx errors were gone once I upgraded WebStorm to `2023.2.3`.

Comment: Interesting, perhaps I should have a look further into that, as the error's were coming from npm run serve, i didnt think this could be a cause.